# Curses printw() willl only print a newline, when fed a string received from the network

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, user-interface, ncurses

I'm currently developing a threaded network application (well, two actually, but with a common base), and am using nCurses for the interface.

The problem is, that currently I am trying to start two threads; the GUI thread is listening for the keyboard to fire, and, when it does, will build a message up in memory. When enter is pressed, this is passed over to the server thread, which passes it over the network.

The server thread listens for a connection. When it receives one, it enters a loop; look if there is any data from the connection, if there is, send it to the GUI thread, which then displays it. Then, check for anything from the GUI, send it over the network, and so on.

The problem is, that I can receive messages just fine (been testing with Telnet up until this point...), and the message gets to the GUI thread fine. printf will display it just fine (however it feels dirty mixing printf and nCurses), but printw will just present me with a newline for my trouble. When I individually access characters, things seem to work.

```
char* messageRcv;
messageRcv = stream_rcv_nblock(stream);

if(messageRcv != NULL) {
    if(messageRcv[0] != '\xFF') {
        printw("%s", messageRcv);
        refresh();
    }

    free(messageRcv);
}
```

This is the code which should, in theory, display the message. For the record, 0xFF is acting, for now, as the 'connection has closed' code. Quick and dirty, but this is very early days right now, so I don't care.

Any assistance with this issue would be greatly appreciated, as I have nothing. Thanks.

EDIT: printw() uses a format string "%s", however the error still occurs.

Comment: Is that pseudo code because it isn't correct?  `Printw` is just like `printf` in that it takes a format string and then parameters.  Are you sure the newline you are experiencing isn't in the network stream itself and you are unknowingly printing it out because you don't check for it?

Comment: If that was the case, surely I'd get "string\n" outputting, rather than just "\n"? Also, `printw` works just the same, in this instance, with the format string as "%s", and as it is shown here, as far as I'm aware...

Comment: Are you sure messageRcv contains a complete '\0' terminated string? Try printing  messageRcv[0..n] as decimals or the string length.  You've probably got a '\0' you are not expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the problem is that your string contains CR-LF sequences at the end of each line.

When `addch` (which is used by `printw`) is asked to output a newline, it first does a `clrtoeol`, and then advances the cursor to the next line. Since the CR causes the cursor position to be reset to the left-hand margin, the `clrtoeol` output by the NL will erase all the characters in the line which was just printed.

As far as I know, there is no way to defeat this behaviour other than removing the CRs from the output.